# PHP isn't properly inputting MySql data

Tags: php, mysql

I've been attempting to place a simple entry into MySql with PHP, I've been trying to learn this with no avail and my database is solid. I'm just trying to see what is wrong with my syntax, any help is much appreciated. When I run it within the terminal it runs properly, admittedly I'm very new to this and am only trying to get some insight into what is wrong with this. I've been messing with this for so long and am not getting anywhere.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect(Minion, "Chris", "Password", ZooProject);
    if (!link) {
        echo "error";
        exit;
    }
    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Animals (animal_id, name, breed_id, sex, Origional_Place, info, birth_date) VALUES ('2','Chris','1','M','idk','test','2000-02-02')");

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

my database description

```
+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| animal_id       | int(11)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(30)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| breed_id        | int(11)           | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sex             | enum('M','F','U') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Origional_Place | varchar(30)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| info            | varchar(140)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| birth_date      | date              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've been looking into the documentation for a while and am just not getting what I need from it when I use the errno command I get an error 0 and I'm on PHP 7.0

Comment: I'm just looking for any advice, I'm new here and am just in the beginning of my learning

Comment: is there already an `animal` with id 2 in your table ? You should not specify explicitly an id for `INSERT` statements if you have `auto_increment`

Comment: Check your PHP log for errors.  `mysqli_query()` seems to be missing an argument.

Comment: Look at the docs for `mysqli_query()` once more - you're missing an argument

Comment: I've checked for another animal with a primary key of 2 and there wasn't when I launch it in the terminal I can run it with a semicolon

Comment: I'll look into the mysqli_query, thank you for the response

Comment: @Chrisscully: Also, while checking the documentation for `mysqli_query()`, take a look at the examples.  You should additionally check the response of the query.  If it's `false`, you would use `mysqli_error()` to check for errors from the database.  They don't get reported to PHP by default, you have to explicitly check for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`$link = mysqli_connect(Minion, "Chris", "Password") or die(mysqli_error());`

`$db = mysqli_select_db($link, ZooProject) or die(mysqli_error());`

Minion = IP and ZooProject is your databasename which should be written in doublequotes like "ZooProjects"

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` really requires 4 parameters. `mysqli_select_db()` is only meant to change databases after a default has been set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mysqli::select_db($dbname) first to select the database. For some reason i had a similar problems few days ago and i think that solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll look into it in a moment

Comment: Selecting the database in the construct does the same, this won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you need to pass the connection object through as the first parameter.

```
<?php
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO Animals (animal_id, name, breed_id, sex, Origional_Place, info, birth_date) VALUES ('2','Chris','1','M','idk','test','2000-02-02')");
```